# Nginx caching DNS look ups and ignoring my resolver settings

Tags: docker, nginx, dns

I am using docker swarm. I placed an nginx container in front of my API for caching purposes. Since every time I deploy my API it creates a new internal IP  I am using the name of my service tasks.api as per swarm documentation. Below is my location block

```
proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx/ta_api levels=1:2 keys_zone=api_cache:10m max_size=10g
                  inactive=60m use_temp_path=off;

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://tasks.api:10010;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_buffering on;
      proxy_cache api_cache;
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
      # Add header to see if response was cached
      add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;

      # Allow one cache-update request at a time sent to an origin server.
      proxy_cache_lock on;
      # Permit revalidation of stale cached responses.
      proxy_cache_revalidate on;

      # proxy_cache_valid 200 1d;
      # Delivering Cached Content When the Origin is Down
      proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout invalid_header updating
                            http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;

      # Do all updates in background. With proxy_cache_use_stale, allows stale
      # cached responses to be served.
      proxy_cache_background_update on;
    }
}
```

I also added `resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off valid=15s;` to my http block. However, when I redeploy my API and it gets a new API nginx still attempts to send to the old IP.

I am running an nginx container tag `nginx:1.15.12-alpine` when I install bind-tools on the nginx container I can see that I am getting the new IPs using `dig tasks.api`

I am at a loss what to try next. I can hardcode private IPs, but that is not the docker way...

Comment: use legacy linking, so first, you need to up your `tasks.api` container then nginx, or second assign static IP to your `tasks.api` container

Comment: @Adiii Swarm doesn't use legacy linking, it creates a user defined network for your app as mentioned [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#/links). This is recommended in the [Legacy Linking](https://docs.docker.com/network/links/) Docker docs. Is there some other alternative?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/v17.12/docker-cloud/apps/service-links/#service-environment-variables

Answer (score 11):

[NGINX will only do DNS lookups at startup and cache forever for *fixed* hostnames](https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,215830,215832#msg-215832). To enable DNS lookup during runtime, you need to change the fixed hostname to a dynamic variable. So in the OP case, change the original `proxy_pass` line to:

```
set $target_host tasks.api ;
proxy_pass http://$target_host:10010;
```

Comment: NGINX blog post detailing all the options here - https://www.nginx.com/blog/dns-service-discovery-nginx-plus/